# Camera not working in Google Nexus tablet

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, google-nexus

I'm trying to open camera from my app. My Camera activity code looks below -

```
      Button click  = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.captureclick);
 if (!getPackageManager()
        .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
    } else {
      cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
      if (cameraId < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found." + cameraId,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else {
          Toast.makeText(this, "cameraId : "+cameraId,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
      }
    }

  click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             camera.takePicture(null, null,
                    new PhotoHandler(CameraActivity.this));
        }
      });

    @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
    if (camera != null) {
      camera.release();
      camera = null;
    }
  }

  private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
      CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
      Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
      }
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        cameraId = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return cameraId;
  }
```

Now I've PhotoHandler.class which looks as below -

```
        public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

       private final Context context;

         public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
         this.context = context;
         }

     @Override
     public void onPictureTaken( final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
    // save data on storage
      }
     }
```

Problem I'm facing is when I click on camera button from my device then call is not going to Photohandler class. I'm getting error below in log -

```
I/CameraClient(128): Opening camera 0
I/NvOmxCamera(128): HAL_camera_device_open: open camera 0
E/(128): ioctl SetWhiteBalance failed: -1
E/NvOmxCameraSettingsParser(128): Param type 70 not supported
I/NvOmxCamera(128): HAL_camera_device_open: opened camera 0 (0x41fc07e0)
D/Camera 01(2958): Finish Opening Camera
I/ActivityManager(485): Displayed com.example.testlogin/.CameraActivity: +148ms
D/Camera 1(2958): Clicked on Camera
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(128): NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 1 
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(128): NvMMLiteJPEGEncGetBufferRequirements : BufferSize 1843200
D/(128): Camera fd open as: 131
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(128): Image Physically rotated in DZ
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(128): NvMMExif_Orientation_0_Degrees= 1
E/NvOmxCamera(128): OMX_ERRORTYPE android::NvOmxCamera::getCameraStereoMode(NvxComponent*, NvOmxCameraUserStereoMode&): Error: invalid NVX mode 0.
E/NvOmxCamera(128): OMX_ERRORTYPE android::NvOmxCamera::getCameraStereoModeAndCaptureInfo(NvxComponent*, NvOmxCameraUserStereoMode&, NVX_STEREOCAPTUREINFO&): getCameraStereoMode failed with 0x00000000
D/NvOsDebugPrintf(128): NvMMLiteJPEGEncSetAttribute: Incorrect value 0 for stereo capture type
/NvOmxCameraSettings(128): OMX_ERRORTYPE android::programStereoInfo(OMX_HANDLETYPE, const NVX_STEREOCAPTUREINFO&, android::NvxWrappers*): pNvxWrappers->OMX_SetConfigIL failed with 0x80001005
```

I did not find any solution for this. Please help me.

Comment: I've run into the same issue on my Nexus7; if I figure it out, I'll post the solution.